# Is there a pattern to where various industrial AC voltages are used?

Tags: voltage, ac, standard

AC voltages in the "low voltage" class vary quite a bit. I've seen nominal voltages of 208, 220-240, 277, 380-415, 460-480, 575-600, and 690 VAC. Past that I don't see anything until medium voltage and 2.2 kVAC. I have the vague idea that 575-600 VAC is common in Canada, 460-480 VAC and 220-240 VAC are common in the US, and 380-415 VAC are common the rest of the world. But that's just a vague idea, and doesn't cover 690 VAC at all.

Are there standards defining which voltage is used where or under what circumstances? Does it really vary with country or region that clearly? Is it more application-based?

Comment: Railway systems - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_systems_for_electric_rail_traction  Domestic systems (much more uniform) http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/

Comment: Some of what you are seeing also changed over time, leading to different commercial standards within a few blocks of each other depending on who renovated first. Older buildings in Houston still have 240/208/120 combination systems.

Answer (score -3):

IEC 60038 recommends all A.C equipment nominal voltages (100< x <1000V) to be within the range of +/-10% to 230/400V system. this is irrespective of country/utility.

Soon we may narrow all our design to 230/400V system.

Comment: This isn't a relevant answer -1

Comment: It's not even true. IEC 60038 also defines 120V. The conversion schedule mentioned was for the 220 and 240 volt suppliers only.